# ¿Como agregar imágenes a un template de correo en Cake PHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake, cakephp-3.x

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, agregue un template html que yo misma cree para que sea visualizado en el correo enviado desde mi sistema pero al recibirlo me doy cuenta que no se visualizan mis logos.

Este es mi codigo del template para el correo la ruta esta src/template/layout/Email/html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
            <header>
            </header>

        <table width="560" cellpadding="27">
            <tr height=76>
                <td style="background:#393c3e;padding:.73pt 27px .73pt 20px;height:57.0pt">
                    <img src="gomx.svg" width="126" height="44" border="0">
                    <img src="logotipo__s--bco.svg" width="110" height="48" border="0" align="right">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height=400>
                <td valign="top">
                    <p marginwidth = "27px">
                        <font color="#5A5A5A"  face="Arial" size="3.5">
                            <strong>Titulo o subtitulo</strong><br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor<br>
                            <br>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Links de referencía
                                </a>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor, Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor<br>
                            <br>            
                        </font>
                    </p>
                    <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;padding: 40px 0;">
                    <button style="border: none; font-size: 18px;border-radius: 3px;padding: 12px 25px;box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #1b5dab;color: #fff;background-color: #4A90E2;border-color: #3483de;" type="button">Call to action buttom</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr  height=76>
                <td width="50%" style="width:50.0%;background:#393c3e;padding:.73pt 27px .73pt 22px;height:57.0pt">
                    <img src="gomx.svg" width="75" height="32" border="0">
                    <img src="logo_mexico.svg" width="86" height="35" align="right" border="0">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nose que este haciendo mal, alguien podría ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera, desde la funcion que tengo en UsersMaile, cargo la imagen dentro de attachments pongo un id y el id lo llamo en el html

```
$this
   ->from(['contacto@dgb.email' => 'Contacto Red Prepa Abierta'])
   ->to($user->email)
   ->emailFormat('both')
   ->subject(sprintf('Bienvenido %s', $user->nombre))
   ->attachments([

            'img.png'=>[
            'file'=>ROOT.DS.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.'img.png',
            'mimetype'=>'image/png',
            'contentId'=>'734h3r38'
            ],
          ])
          ->template('welcome', 'default'); 
    }
```

En el HTML  llamo el contentId quedo asi:

```
<img src="cid:734h3r36" width="110" height="48" border="0" align="right">
```